# Using Sagemaker predictor in a Spark UDF function

Tags: tensorflow, pyspark, amazon-sagemaker

I am trying to run inference on a Tensorflow model deployed on SageMaker from a Python Spark job.
I am running a (Databricks) notebook which has the following cell:

```
def call_predict():
        batch_size = 1
        data = [[0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.2]]
        tensor_proto = tf.make_tensor_proto(values=np.asarray(data), shape=[batch_size, len(data[0])], dtype=tf.float32)      
        prediction = predictor.predict(tensor_proto)
        print("Process time: {}".format((time.clock() - start)))
        return prediction
```

If I just call call_predict() it works fine:

```
call_predict()
```

and I get the output:

```
Process time: 65.261396
Out[61]: {'model_spec': {'name': u'generic_model',
  'signature_name': u'serving_default',
  'version': {'value': 1578909324L}},
 'outputs': {u'ages': {'dtype': 1,
   'float_val': [5.680944442749023],
   'tensor_shape': {'dim': [{'size': 1L}]}}}}
```

but when I try to call from a Spark context (in a UDF) I get a serialization error.
The code I'm trying to run is:

```
dataRange = range(1, 10001)
rangeRDD = sc.parallelize(dataRange, 8)
new_data = rangeRDD.map(lambda x : call_predict())
new_data.count()
```

and the error I get is:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
PicklingError                             Traceback (most recent call last)
<command-2282434> in <module>()
      2 rangeRDD = sc.parallelize(dataRange, 8)
      3 new_data = rangeRDD.map(lambda x : call_predict())
----> 4 new_data.count()
      5 

/databricks/spark/python/pyspark/rdd.pyc in count(self)
   1094         3
   1095         """
-> 1096         return self.mapPartitions(lambda i: [sum(1 for _ in i)]).sum()
   1097 
   1098     def stats(self):

/databricks/spark/python/pyspark/rdd.pyc in sum(self)
   1085         6.0
   1086         """
-> 1087         return self.mapPartitions(lambda x: [sum(x)]).fold(0, operator.add)
   1088 
   1089     def count(self):

/databricks/spark/python/pyspark/rdd.pyc in fold(self, zeroValue, op)
    956         # zeroValue provided to each partition is unique from the one provided
    957         # to the final reduce call
--> 958         vals = self.mapPartitions(func).collect()
    959         return reduce(op, vals, zeroValue)
    960 

/databricks/spark/python/pyspark/rdd.pyc in collect(self)
    829         # Default path used in OSS Spark / for non-credential passthrough clusters:
    830         with SCCallSiteSync(self.context) as css:
--> 831             sock_info = self.ctx._jvm.PythonRDD.collectAndServe(self._jrdd.rdd())
    832         return list(_load_from_socket(sock_info, self._jrdd_deserializer))
    833 

/databricks/spark/python/pyspark/rdd.pyc in _jrdd(self)
   2573 
   2574         wrapped_func = _wrap_function(self.ctx, self.func, self._prev_jrdd_deserializer,
-> 2575                                       self._jrdd_deserializer, profiler)
   2576         python_rdd = self.ctx._jvm.PythonRDD(self._prev_jrdd.rdd(), wrapped_func,
   2577                                              self.preservesPartitioning, self.is_barrier)

/databricks/spark/python/pyspark/rdd.pyc in _wrap_function(sc, func, deserializer, serializer, profiler)
   2475     assert serializer, "serializer should not be empty"
   2476     command = (func, profiler, deserializer, serializer)
-> 2477     pickled_command, broadcast_vars, env, includes = _prepare_for_python_RDD(sc, command)
   2478     return sc._jvm.PythonFunction(bytearray(pickled_command), env, includes, sc.pythonExec,
   2479                                   sc.pythonVer, broadcast_vars, sc._javaAccumulator)

/databricks/spark/python/pyspark/rdd.pyc in _prepare_for_python_RDD(sc, command)
   2461     # the serialized command will be compressed by broadcast
   2462     ser = CloudPickleSerializer()
-> 2463     pickled_command = ser.dumps(command)
   2464     if len(pickled_command) > sc._jvm.PythonUtils.getBroadcastThreshold(sc._jsc):  # Default 1M
   2465         # The broadcast will have same life cycle as created PythonRDD

/databricks/spark/python/pyspark/serializers.pyc in dumps(self, obj)
    709                 msg = "Could not serialize object: %s: %s" % (e.__class__.__name__, emsg)
    710             cloudpickle.print_exec(sys.stderr)
--> 711             raise pickle.PicklingError(msg)
    712 
    713 

PicklingError: Could not serialize object: TypeError: can't pickle _ssl._SSLSocket objects
```

Not sure what is this serialization error - does is complain about failing to deserialize the Predictor

My notebook has a cell which was called prior to the above cells with the following imports:

```
import sagemaker
import boto3
from sagemaker.tensorflow.model import TensorFlowPredictor
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np
import time
```

The Predictor was created with the following code:

```
sagemaker_client = boto3.client('sagemaker', aws_access_key_id=ACCESS_KEY,
                                aws_secret_access_key=SECRET_KEY, region_name='us-east-1')
sagemaker_runtime_client = boto3.client('sagemaker-runtime', aws_access_key_id=ACCESS_KEY,
                                        aws_secret_access_key=SECRET_KEY, region_name='us-east-1')

boto_session = boto3.Session(region_name='us-east-1')
sagemaker_session = sagemaker.Session(boto_session, sagemaker_client=sagemaker_client, sagemaker_runtime_client=sagemaker_runtime_client)

predictor = TensorFlowPredictor('endpoint-poc', sagemaker_session)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The udf function will be executed by multiple spark tasks in parallel. Those tasks run in completely isolated python processes and they are scheduled to physically different machines. Hence each data, those functions reference, must be on the same node. This is the case for everything created within the udf.

Whenever you reference any object outside of the udf from the function, this data structure needs to be serialised (pickled) to each executor. Some object state, like open connections to a socket, cannot be pickled.

You need to make sure, that connections are lazily opened each executor. It must happen only on the first function call on that executor. The [connection pooling topic](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/streaming-programming-guide.html#design-patterns-for-using-foreachrdd) is covered in the docs, however only in the spark streaming guide (though it also applies for normal batch jobs).

Normally one can use the Singleton Pattern for this. But in python people use the Borgh pattern.

```
class Env:
    _shared_state = {
        "sagemaker_client": None
        "sagemaker_runtime_client": None
        "boto_session": None
        "sagemaker_session": None
        "predictor": None
    }
    def __init__(self):
        self.__dict__ = self._shared_state
        if not self.predictor:
            self.sagemaker_client = boto3.client('sagemaker', aws_access_key_id=ACCESS_KEY, aws_secret_access_key=SECRET_KEY, region_name='us-east-1')
            self.sagemaker_runtime_client = boto3.client('sagemaker-runtime', aws_access_key_id=ACCESS_KEY, aws_secret_access_key=SECRET_KEY, region_name='us-east-1')

            self.boto_session = boto3.Session(region_name='us-east-1')
            self.sagemaker_session = sagemaker.Session(self.boto_session, sagemaker_client=self.sagemaker_client, sagemaker_runtime_client=self.sagemaker_runtime_client)

            self.predictor = TensorFlowPredictor('endpoint-poc', self.sagemaker_session)


#....
def call_predict():
   env = Env()
   batch_size = 1
   data = [[0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.2]]
   tensor_proto = tf.make_tensor_proto(values=np.asarray(data), shape=[batch_size, len(data[0])], dtype=tf.float32)      
   prediction = env.predictor.predict(tensor_proto)

   print("Process time: {}".format((time.clock() - start)))
        return prediction

new_data = rangeRDD.map(lambda x : call_predict())
```

The Env class is defined on the master node. Its `_shared_state` has empty entries. When then Env object is instantiated first time, it shares the state with all further instances of Env on any subsequent call to the udf. On each separate parallel running process this will happen exactly one time. This way the sessions are shared and do not need to pickled.

Comment: Thanks for your answer @dre-hh - it solves my problem, but I think your explanation may be misleading to future readers. The UDF function does not hold a copy of the model, it only has the Predictor which calls the model that is deployed on a separate endpoint (in Sagemekr in that case). The serialization problem I encountered was about not being to pickle the _ssl._SSLSocket objects which I think are part of the boto client session. As now, with your code the boto session is initialized in the _shared_state the serialization issue is resolved.

Comment: Sure. It happens also a lot with ML models. The pattern is similar. Changed the description.